# Firefox localstorage values sometimes missing in new tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, storage

I am facing a strange issue in Firefox (62.0.3). The values set in `localStorage` are sometimes lost in a new tab.

I can reproduce this with the following HTML, when served by a web server (I used node/express).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body><script>
    window.onload = () => {console.log(window.localStorage.myVal || 'undefined')}
</script></body></html>
```

Steps:

1. open page, page displays `undefined`
2. run script in console `localStorage.myVal='defined'`
3. reload page, page displays `defined`
4. when opening the page in a new tab it displays `undefined` or `defined` at random. (I opened 10 new tabs and results seemed random)

Maybe I have set something in Firefox which causes this, but since the behaviour is at random I am somewhat puzzled.

The example above is just to demonstrate the problem. The Actual application where this problem first happened was a react/redux application using localStorage.

Comment: Try `window.onload = () => {console.log(window.localStorage.myVal || 'undefined')}` and see it it works this way.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: NEVER document.write after load - it wipes the page AND the script

Comment: replacing write with log did not change behaviour

Comment: Did you ever make progress on this? I am facing the exact same issue with Firefox 66.0.2 on Ubuntu. Annoyingly, appearance of the bug is somewhat random.

Comment: @tglas: Unfortunately not. It remains to be somewhat annoying, but I have shifted development work to chrome in the meantime. I believe the problem relates to some restrictive privacy setting I have made, but I was unable to determine which one and I didn't find the time to reset all my settings to truly test this. As a side note, I never escalated this to any other board or bug tracker.

Comment: @Philippe: Yesterday I disabled the setting "Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed", where I had defined proper exceptions so that it should not have an effect on my test case. However, after disabling the setting, localStorage started to work as it should. This is a pity, since I really hate to disable that privacy option.

Comment: @tglas: Strange, one would assume this setting only affects Firefox on exit and not opening new tabs. Does not sound like a feature to me:). But thanks a lot, I will try this later.

Comment: 3 years later, and I'm experiencing the same issue. The "Delete cookies..." setting was disabled in the first place, so this was not the solution for me. It also works fine in Chrome for me.

Comment: I believe there are remaining issues with Firefox local storage. Even now I have a problem with it sometimes losing localstorage settings if there is not enough time before a redirect. I think there is probably some asynchronous commit that still happens so it's timing sensitive. 
They did a big rewrite called "Next-gen local storage" (NGLS) but I don't know if it fixed this issue.